# lightning-record-edit-form invalid API Name

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm getting an error when I cut and paste the lightning-record-edit-form from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation

I've changed record-id to a legal value on my org.

```
 <lightning-record-edit-form 
      record-id="0126A000000VIAKQA4"
      object-api-name="Contact">
       <lightning-messages>
       </lightning-messages>
       <lightning-output-field field-name="AccountId">
       </lightning-output-field>
       <lightning-input-field field-name="FirstName">
       </lightning-input-field>
       <lightning-input-field field-name="LastName">
       </lightning-input-field>
       <lightning-input-field field-name="Email">
       </lightning-input-field>
       <lightning-button
            class="slds-m-top_small"
            variant="brand"
            type="submit"
            name="update"
            label="Update">
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

And I'm seeing this error.  Contact is the same API name used in the example.  I'm at a loss to think what might be wrong with it?

[image: error from]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What kind of Id is the one in the record-id attribute ? Is it a Id from a Contact record of your org ? If not, this is the problem here ! You have to put a Contact Record Id for this attribute